# why does my try and except validation not work when verifying my net code?

Tags: python, python-requests, try-except

I'm trying to write some code to give me an error when the requests module isn't able to pull the html from a website correctly by verifying the net code is 200. as I've written it below, (if I understand correctly) if the "except" parameter is applicable, it wont run anything under the "try" parameter (in the case printing a success statement). you'll see if you run this `print status` returns `none`, and despite that fulfilling the "except" parameter, the "try" print line is executed. where am I going wrong?

```
#import modules
import bs4, requests, pyperclip, re

#designate the website
website = "https://grocery.walmart.com/browse/Fresh-Fruit?=&Vegetables_CP_Cat_Anchor_Fresh_Fruit=&aisle=1255027787131_1255027788181&page=1&povid=1255027787131%20%7C%20contentZone3%20%7C%202019-05-29%20%7C%201%20%7C%20Fruits&"
# website = "https://amazon.com/Automate-Boring-Stuff-Python-2nd-ebook/dp/B07VSXS4NK/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=automate+the+boring+stuff&qid=1586981494&sr=8-1"

#pull the html from the website
#checks for net code to verify the html pulled correctly

siteHTML = requests.get(website)
status = siteHTML.raise_for_status()
print(status)
try:
        print("HTML request attempt successful!",)
except status != "<bound method Response.raise_for_status of <Response [200]>>":
    #searches for the net code using regular expression
    codeRegex = re.compile(r'(\d){3}')
    code = codeRegex.search(status)
    print("requests attempt unsuccessful. received net code %s",code.group(0))
```

Comment: You have used the `try.. except` incorrectly. So, `try` must contain the block of code, which has the potential to cause an exception, and `except` will catch that error and execute the code written within it.

Comment: Thanks Calvin, I'll look more into that and rewrite my try and except.

Answer (score 1):

`raise_for_status()` will raise an error if the status is non-2xx. This is the error you need to catch, so this function needs to be in the `try` block. Then you can catch the `HTTPError` that results from a bad request. Something like:

```
siteHTML = requests.get("http://example.com/badPath")

try:
    siteHTML.raise_for_status()
    print("success")
except requests.HTTPError as err:
    print(err)
```

Prints:

```
404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http://example.com/badPath
```

Comment: thank you! you've answered another question I had about non-2xx statuses returning as errors. I appreciate the feedback and the reasoning, if I have any more questions / need more clarification i'll follow up. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

website = "https://grocery.walmart.com/browse/Fresh-Fruit?=&Vegetables_CP_Cat_Anchor_Fresh_Fruit=&aisle=1255027787131_1255027788181&page=1&povid=1255027787131%20%7C%20contentZone3%20%7C%202019-05-29%20%7C%201%20%7C%20Fruits&"

r = requests.get(website)
print(r.status_code)
if r.status_code == 200:
    print("HTML request attempt successful!",)
else:
    print("requests attempt unsuccessful. received net code {}".format(r.status_code))
```